Pytorch GRU Model Isn't learning on time series with target value
I encountered a strange problem with my Neural Network not learning, here is the short story:

I took the weather data of daily format
I generated lag features and etc (did some data engineering)
I used Random Forest to gather the most important features and got 3000 features (columns)

After that I was confused what to do next and I looked up, that if you want to use dataframe with consecutive rows, you should make sequence and here is how I did it:
def create_sequences(features, target, seq_length):
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(len(features) - seq_length)):
        X.append(features.iloc[i:i+seq_length])

        y.append(target.iloc[i+seq_length])
    return np.array(X,dtype=np.float32), np.array(y)

seq_length = 5
X_temporal_train, y_temporal_train = create_sequences(X, y.astype(bool), seq_length)

After creating these variables, I used StandardScaler:
X_temporal_train_flat = X_temporal_train.reshape(-1, X_temporal_train.shape[-1])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_temporal_train_flat_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_temporal_train_flat)

X_temporal_train_scaled = X_temporal_train_flat_scaled.reshape(X_temporal_train.shape)

After that I splitted on train and test numpy array and got this shape for train array:
(9960, 5, 3000)

Right after I created Tensor Dataset and DataLoader:
X_train_tensor = torch.tensor(X_train, dtype=torch.float32)
y_train_tensor = torch.tensor(y_train, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1) #My target is binary, so I guess this is the right way to do it
train_dataset = TensorDataset(X_train_tensor, y_train_tensor)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

Next, I created GRU Model, which works with binary target:
class GRUNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, num_layers=1):
        super(GRUNet, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.gru = nn.GRU(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True,dropout=0.1,bidirectional=False)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(x.device)
        out, _ = self.gru(x, h0)
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        return out

model = GRUNet(3000, 128, 1, 3)

Here is my training loop of the model:
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

lr= 0.001
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=lr,amsgrad=True)
scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, mode='min', factor=0.1, patience=20, verbose=True)

num_epochs = 1000
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)

import tqdm

for epoch in tqdm.tqdm(range(num_epochs)):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for X_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
        outputs = model(X_batch)
        
        loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
        
    # Validation
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X_batch, y_batch in test_loader:
            X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
            outputs = model(X_batch)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
            val_loss += loss.item()

    val_loss /= len(val_loader)
    scheduler.step(val_loss)
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}, Test Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')
    
    early_stopping(val_loss, model)
    if early_stopping.early_stop:
        print("Early stopping")
        break

Here is my question: No matter how long it trains, what is the learning rate or depth of the model, the result is always approximately the same: Loss: 0.6935, Test Loss: 2.7711. Loss can become like: Loss: 0.6926, Test Loss: 2.7708 or Loss: 0.6883, Test Loss: 2.7694, but not lower than these numbers. What am I doing wrong?
I tried various architectures from most complex to just linear without GRU layers, but the result is always the same. I heard that one way or another, the model should at least overfit or get close to 0 loss, but in my case, the model's loss is the same even after 200-300 epochs.
Just in case: my max and min values in dataframe before transformation: 398320300195840.0,-99965362176.0
